# Помогите сгенерировать barcode такого вида

Tags: java, barcode

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помоги сгенерировать такой barcode, какими библиотеками можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь просто линии:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class BarCodeGenerator {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("_________");
                BarCodePanel barCodePanel = new BarCodePanel(new Line[]{
                        new Line(3),
                        new Line(2),
                        new Line(4),
                        new Line(3),
                        new Line(2),
                        new Line(6),
                        new Line(4),
                        new Line(5),
                        new Line(7),
                        new Line(5),
                        new Line(3),
                        new Line(4),
                        new Line(9),
                        new Line(12),
                        new Line(11),
                        new Line(3),
                        new Line(6),
                        new Line(3),
                        new Line(2),
                        new Line(8)
                });
                frame.add(barCodePanel);
                frame.setSize(1000, 600);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            });
        }
    }

    class BarCodePanel extends JPanel {
        private Line[] lines;

        public BarCodePanel(Line[] lines) {
            this.lines = lines;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
            int x = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    g2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                } else {
                    g2D.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
                Line line = lines[i];
                g2D.fillRect(x, 0, line.getWidth(), 60);
                x += line.getWidth();
            }

        }
    }

    class Line {
        private int width;

        public Line(int width) {
            this.width = width;
        }

        public int getWidth() {
            return width;
        }
    }
```

Если нужны еще и цифры, нужен алгоритм.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на [Barcode4j](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/). Правда именно такого как у Вас на картинке там нет штрих-кода в примерах, но думаю можно что-нибудь придумать.